# turn-on: couldn't complete because some conditions were not met

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

We're using 2sxc 15.8 and on some pages the fancybox works and on other pages we get something like:

> turn-on: #1 couldn't complete because some conditions were not met.
> See details:   [{…}] 0 :  {type: 'window-key', ready: false, message:
> "tried up to max attempts: Not all keys matched yet. So far
> 'window.appContent' worked.", name: 'window.appContent.initFancybox',
> result: undefined, …} length :  1

So is there something we can do about this?

Answer (score 0):

[TurnOn](https://docs.2sxc.org/js-code/turn-on/index.html) is a system which will check if all necessary scripts are loaded, and will then trigger the init call.

If you see this message, it appears that some expected scripts are not loading - either because they are blocked by something, or because the razor template forgot to request it.

You are probably using the Content app. My suggestion is you check your network with F12 (in case you're blocking certain requests such as CDNs).

It could also be that a single template forgot to request these scripts. In that case it would work on most pages but just not on a specific one - which you could then add.